# How come Fury and Hill could not identify Quentin Beck?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far from Home*, Hill and Fury are investigating an unnatural storm in Ixtenco Mexico.

This is an earth elemental of Mysterio's orchestration.

With the unnatural storm data and the access Hill and Fury have to facial recognition and other identification technologies, how come Fury and Hill could not identify Quentin Beck, a former engineer specialist from the holographic illusions division of Stark Industries R&D department deriving that he is the cause of the unnatural storm upon arriving in Ixtenco Mexico?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with...

That's not Nick Fury and Maria Hill...as we later find out it's actually Talos and Soren who are Skrulls masquerading as them.

Talos even says at the end of the movie

> Come on, Soren, how was I supposed to know the whole thing was fake? I mean, that was all very, very convincing, you know. The performances, the illusion, that costume, the craftsmanship in that. I mean, this is just embarrassing for a shape-shifter.

Clearly they were taken in by Beck's story and, as has been said elsewhere...even if they did use their information sources (not SHIELD's apparently) all that would do is confirm that Mysterio *looks like* Quentin Beck.

But that in itself means nothing since he never denies being Quentin Beck...he's just **a different** Quentin Beck from another universe.

The fact that the supposed "real" Beck is a hologram expert doesn't necessarily mean that they should be suspicious since holograms can't affect physical objects.

They aren't to know that Beck has actually assembled a team to fake the disasters...

> The integration of my illusion tech, with your **weaponized drones**, was brilliant. Powerful illusions, **real damage**, worked like a charm. And it's just the beginning.

> Staging **electromagnetic pulses at each attack site so Fury's own satellites would confirm our lies?** Inspired idea. To Janice!

Comment: Thank you answering my question. Do you think Jake Gyllenhaal image is Mysterio's true face?  Wouldn't that be quite a twist if Mysterio's true face were revealed as another actors image.

Comment: There's no reason to think that's not his real face especially as we see his face with all the holograms turned off on a couple of occasions.

Comment: sure but that could somehow be a layered hologram afterall he is Mysterio and his true face remains a mystery until his death.

Comment: Let's not get silly now.... ☺